# Searching with multiple parameters in ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, search

I need to perform a search on a `MapServer` that populates a datagrid with the resulting information such as in this example [Show find task results in a DataGrid](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/find_map_datagrid.html). However, I need to be able to have multiple parameters to search for at the same time. For instance, I need to search for a person at a specific address.

I am using [findParameters()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/findparameters-amd.html) and [findTask()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/findtask-amd.html) but I don't see how I can use multiple parameters in a `searchText`.

Comment: I have not figured this out yet either though I suspect the answer is to have separate searches. I can have multiple search fields but it uses the same criteria for both searches e.g. search for "42" might search for 42 in MAP and PARCEL and will return either as a hit.

Comment: I see what you mean but I'm trying to have it so I can have someone search by selecting a `location` and `date` to basically narrow down the search and not bring up every possible location or date. Hope that makes more sense.